# How can I append to a <h1> tag inside a span with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTubp/)

I'm trying to append some text to a heading that is in a span. But I don't know how to append to the actual heading, and not just the span.

Style:

```
h1 {font-size:250%;color:red;}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="note">
    <h1>
        some text
    </h1>
</span>
```

I run this:

```
$('.note:first-child').append("more text");
```

But the text gets appended after the heading tag, and therefore doesn't have the heading style applied to it. How can I append to the heading?

Comment: not cool to put block element into inline element

Comment: @Eimantas: Maybe there's `.note h1 { display:inline; }` somewhere in CSS. I've seen styles like this to have semantic tags for inline headers of short messages and thing like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bTubp/2/

```
$('.note h1:first-child').append("more text");
```

for inserting inside the first `h1` of every `.note` class

and

```
$('.note:first-child h1').append("more text");
```

for inserting inside text for `h1` of first `.note` class

For first `h1` of first `.note`

```
$('.note:first-child h1:first-child').append("more text");
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the nature of the selectors, and I think you first example gets at exactly what the OP intended.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space for your selector to do what you mean:

```
$('.note :first-child').append("more text");
```

or:

```
$('.note > :first-child').append("more text");
```

See DEMOs:

- http://jsfiddle.net/bTubp/3/
- http://jsfiddle.net/bTubp/4/

When you say: `.note:first-child` it means *something with class note that is also the first child of its parent*. When you say: `.note :first-child` it means *something that is the first child of its parent and is inside (maybe deeply) of something with class note*. When you say: `.note>:first-child` it means: *something that is the first child of its parent and its parent has class note* and this is probably what you meant.

I see that there are already a lot of answers before I finished writing it but I will still post it because I hope it explains **why** your selector didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.note:first-child h1').append("more text");
```

Comment: why would you repeat my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`$(".note h1:first").append("more text");`

This would look for the class ".note", followed by the first h1 tag.